# Find duplicates in objects within an object in underscore

Tags: javascript, object, collections, underscore.js

I have an object like below:

```
result = { 
    1:{name:'john', age: 20, sex:'M'}, 
    2:{name:'smith', age: 25, sex:'M'}, 
    3:{name:'john', age: 20, sex:'M'},
    4:{name:'anna', age: 22, sex:'F'}
}
```

I need to check if each object based on name and age already exists in the table and return true if there is a duplicate.

How would I do that?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to

1. chain the `result` object
2. pass it to `map`, so we can get an array of values i.e. [{name:'john', age: 20, sex:'M'},{name:'smith', age: 25, sex:'M'}, {name:'john', age: 20, sex:'M'},{name:'john', age: 22, sex:'M'},{name:'anna', age: 22, sex:'F'}]
   Remarks: if you don't need the keys i.e. 1:, 2: then get the result as result = [object, object ...]. Then step 2 is not necessary
3. pass it to `groupBy('name')` which will group the arrays in 2 by name
4. pass it to `filter` and filter it where the array length > 1
5. Since the result is nested, pass it to `flatten`
6. Now repeat 3 to 5 for `age`
7. Use `value()` to extract the value of the wrapped object

   ```
     var duplicate = _.chain(result)
                     .map(function(value, key){return value;})
                     .groupBy('name')
                     .filter(function(array){ return array.length > 1})
                     .flatten()
                     .groupBy('age')
                     .filter(function(array){ return array.length > 1})
                     .flatten()
                     .value()
                     .length > 1 ? true: false ;

     console.log(duplicate);
   ```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sameer_kc/y3d2q57s/)